# JQuery Fullcalendar event always on bottom

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have event that always need to be shown underneath other events. I tried to give my css class a z-index but that won't work.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a negative z-index?

Comment: well could you post some code?
can't tell you much by guessing